# filltext without coordinates

Tags: html, canvas, draw

so i have made a circle in the canvas, and i'm trying to have a line of text in it. 
the problem is, the filltext code line generates the text at a particular given coordinate, but i dont want that.

is there a way to have the line of text stay inside the circle?

```
        var programFill = function ( context ) {

                context.beginPath();
                context.arc( 0, 0, 1, 0, PI2, true );

                context.font="20px Georgia";
                context.fillText("Hello World!",10,50);

                context.closePath();

                context.fill();

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Draw filled text inside a circle**

Here's an example of how to put text inside a circle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/BUkKt/

Notice context.beginPath() is called twice because you are doing 2 fills.  The first to draw the filled circle and the second to change the fill color and draw the filled text.

And here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas1.getContext("2d");

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="yellow";
    context.strokeStyle="black";
    context.font="20px Georgia";
    context.lineWidth=10;
    context.arc(100,100, 75, 0 , 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="red";
    context.fillText("Hello World!",40,100);
    context.fill();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br/>
</body>
</html>
```